# pandas read_table usecols error with ":"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a certain range of nonconsecutive columns from my file using python pandas read_table function. To that end, I am trying:

```
df=pd.read_table('genes.fpkm_trackingTest', usecols=[0:4, 8,9, 12:19])
```

The idea is that i am trying to use ":" to select the range of number of columns for usecols, rather than using column numbers separated with comma ",". I am getting a  syntax error. If I use commas "," to separate column numbers, then it works fine.

```
df=pd.read_table('genes.fpkm_trackingTest', usecols=[0,1,2,4, 8,9, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])
```

However, that can be cumbersome as sometimes i have to select 40 columns. How can i come around this?

I even tried

```
usecols=[range(0:4), 8, 9, range(12:19)]
```

but it also gave me errors.

I think that should be simple thing to solve but I couldnt find a solution online.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should be...

Python 3:

```
usecols = [*range(0, 5), 8, 9, *range(12, 20)]
```

Python 2:

```
usecols = range(0, 5) + [8, 9] + range(12, 20)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Was trying to figure out your answer with some reference to either Pandas or Python docs,, not sure how to figure it out myself, ie learning to fish rather than getting it handed to me :-)

Comment: @dartdog I never worked with Pandas, so actually just basic Python stuff. Maybe [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html) can help you!

Comment: Thanks so much, the key seems to be that it is using the list data structure. And the range function.. But one last thing! What is the *range vs range?

Comment: @dartdog It seems like the `*` operator in Python 2 is limited to function calls!

Comment: But what is its purpose in the P3 version not as a multiplier?

Comment: @dartdog It's like somewhat "unpacking" the iterator returned by the `range` function. For example, `[range(0, 3), 3] == [[0, 1, 2], 3]` but `[*range(0, 3), 3] == [0, 1, 2, 3]`.